# The temperature of the chamber B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

**I am studying Thermal Physics and this question raised from a problem I was work on. I don’t want to know the answer, I want to understand it in a conceptual and logic way**

> Suppose we have a chamber with a monoatomic gas. The chamber is divided in two equal parts, $A$ and $B$. The gas is in the chamber $A$, at a temperature $T$. At some moment, and for a short period of time, the gas started to leak through a small hole to the part $B$. What is the final temperature ($T’$) of part $B$?

So in this problem, we assume that in the part A, the molecules follow a Maxwellian Distribution (!*this is a given*!). And we can work out some values such as the mean kinetic energy of one molecule.

I search for this problem and I saw a (small) resolution, it said that: if there are $N$ particles going to $B$, they must have a higher energy (this comes from the effusion phenomena), but the energy of particles in chamber $B$ will end up being of the form:

$$< E > = (3KT’)/2 $$

And so:

$$ N*2*K*T = N*(3KT’)/2 $$

This was I interpreted from the resolution, but I don’t know if am thinking right?

I would really appreciate if someone can judge my thought and correct if I’m wrong.

Comment: As a hint, I will suggest that this is a problem on adiabatic process.

Comment: @LeoL. so it means that are no losses of energy to the surroundings. But exists energy transfer between part A and B. I understand that 2KT will be the energy lost by part A because of molecules effusing.. But why is the energy gain by B given by that expression?

Comment: Rather than thinking about the energy in each of the part A and B, it is easy to think in terms of the total internal energy of the gas initially (only in part A) and finally (in both parts) to determine the final temperature. I will elaborate my comment in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We treat the gas as a thermodynamic system.

First, as the effusion process is only over “a short period of time”, this hints that the process is adiabatic, i.e. there is no heat transfer to the gas system. So $Q=0$.

Next, note that the system does not perform any work during the effusion process, as the pressure in vacuum is zero. So $W=0$.

The first law of thermodynamics is $$\Delta U=Q-W,$$ with the sign convention that Q is heat flow *into* the system and W is work done *by* the system. Therefore, the internal energy of the gas does not change.

As the gas is monoatomic, i.e. $U=\frac{3}{2}k_BNT$, so the temperature of the gas does not change.

For further reading, you can look into https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion

Comment: So the temperature of chamber B will be the same as A?

Comment: Yes, both initially and finally.